# Lag time in a logistic function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems

I would like to ask how it is possible to find a lag time in a logistic function?
I have the function:
$x_{\gamma}(k;t)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-k(t-\gamma)}}$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you state the definition of "lag time"

Comment: The period when the function is growing slow, before the exponential growth occurs.